# Regex split on pipes

Tags: regex

I would like to split the following string:

```
1111AA|10 km|list
```

with a regular expression. I have tried this, but it won't give me the correct result:

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([0-9a-z ]+)|([a-zA-Z]))
```

This only returns the first section: 1111AA

My result should be a split on the pipes.

Comment: Escape the pipes (for example with `[|]`).

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the help.. the escaping of the pipes worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this `"1111AA|10 km|list".split('|')` in JavaScript language.

Answer (score 0):

`|` has special meaning in regular expression. For example, `PatternA|PatternB` matches `PatternA` or `PatternB`.

Escape `|` to match it literally.

Following is Javascript example:

```
'1111AA|10 km|list'.match(/(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\|([0-9a-z ]+)\|([a-zA-Z]))/)
// => ["1111AA|10 km|l", "1111AA|10 km|l", "1111AA", "10 km", "l"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get each group using regex, just escape the pipes:

```
/(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\|([0-9a-z ]+)\|([a-zA-Z]))/
```

You can test regex patterns on http://regex101.com if you are not sure about your expressions. That site will give you feedback on your pattern. Just keep in mind that most special characters will need to be escaped by placing a backslash in front of them.