# Regex to split a column in R after the second pipe and after the second T

Tags: r, regex

I have a 1 column dataframe of thousands of lines all built on the same pattern, for example:

```
ids <- c("ETC|HMPI01000001|HMPI01000001.1 TAG: Genus Species, T05X3Ml2_CL10007Cordes1_1","ETC|HMPI31000002|HMPI31000002.1 TAG: Genus Species, T3X3Ml2_CL10157Cordes1_1", "ETC|HMPI01000007|HMPI01000007.1 TAG: Genus Species, T1X3Ml2_CL11231Cordes1_1")

df <- as.data.frame(ids)
```

```
> df
                                                                            ids
1  ETC|HMPI01000001|HMPI01000001.1 TAG: Genus Species, T05X3Ml2_CL10007Cordes1_1
2  ETC|HMPI31000002|HMPI31000002.1 TAG: Genus Species, T3X3Ml2_CL10157Cordes1_1
3  ETC|HMPI01000007|HMPI01000007.1 TAG: Genus Species, T1X3Ml2_CL11231Cordes1_1
```

I want to split these characters in 2 columns: var1 and var2 such and keep the text after the second pipe and before the first space, and the text from the second T after the space onwards. These will be the common patterns for all the lines. The expected results is:

```
> df
            var1                      var2
1 HMPI01000001.1 T05X3Ml2_CL10007Cordes1_1
2 HMPI31000002.1  T3X3Ml2_CL10157Cordes1_1
3 HMPI01000007.1  T1X3Ml2_CL11231Cordes1_1
```

I have tried several regex inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271530/regex-capture-after-second), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072020/r-regular-expression-match-after-second-or-third-occurence) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280668/regex-split-on-pipes).. But I cannot figure it out.

I have currently this, but it is not giving the expected results:

```
df2 <- df %>% separate(col = "ids", into = c("var1", "var2"), sep = "\\|([^|]+)$")
> df2
              var1 var2
1 ETC|HMPI01000001     
2 ETC|HMPI31000002     
3 ETC|HMPI01000007
```

Any help, preferably using a regex and the tidyverse, would be appreciated.

Comment: If simply matching, and not capturing, the two strings of interest were preferred, and one trusted the structure of the data to be correct, one could match `.*\\|\K\\S+|.*\KT.*` (with `perl=TRUE`). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4PgNes/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(var1 = str_extract(ids, ".*\\|(\\S+)", group = 1),
         var2 = str_extract(ids, ".*, (.*$)", group = 1))
```

You can also use `separate_wider_position`, if their placement is fixed:

```r
library(tidyr)

df |>
  separate_wider_position(ids, 
                          widths = c(17, var1 = 14, 21, var2 = max(nchar(ids))), 
                          too_few = "align_start")

#  var1           var2                     
#  <chr>          <chr>                    
# 1 HMPI01000001.1 T05X3Ml2_CL10007Cordes1_1
# 2 HMPI31000002.1 T3X3Ml2_CL10157Cordes1_1 
# 3 HMPI01000007.1 T1X3Ml2_CL11231Cordes1_1
```

Comment: It is unfortunately not fixed

Answer (score 6):

We can use `strcapture`.

```r
strcapture("^[^|]*\\|[^|]*\\|(\\S+)\\s.*? (T.*)",
           ids, list(var1="", var2=""))
#             var1                      var2
# 1 HMPI01000001.1 T05X3Ml2_CL10007Cordes1_1
# 2 HMPI31000002.1  T3X3Ml2_CL10157Cordes1_1
# 3 HMPI01000007.1  T1X3Ml2_CL11231Cordes1_1
```

Regex:

```
"^[^|]*\\|[^|]*\\|(\\S+)\\s.*? (T.*)"
 ^                                     beginning of string
  [^|]*\\|                             leading up to first |
          [^|]*\\|                     leading up to the second |
                  (\\S+)\\s            non-space (captured) and blank space
                           .*?         non-greedy "anything"
                               (T.*)   literal T (after a space) and everything else
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. How can I use it to separate my columns? I get an error when I use strcapture as my sep = expression

Comment: What `sep=` argument? This is working on your `ids` object.

Comment: Ok. I tried it like this ```df2 <- df %>% strcapture("^[^|]*\\|[^|]*\\|(\\S+)\\s.*? (T.*)",ids, list(var1="", var2="")) ``` and I get the following error: Error in !perl : invalid argument type

Comment: The pipe operator is going to pass the data frame as the first argument of `strcapture` which is the problem. You need to do `strcapture(..., df$ids, ...)`.

Comment: If you are wanting to implement this in `dplyr` you could just stick it in a `mutate` statement so you don't have to reference the data frame (notice only using `ids` here): `df |>
  mutate(strcapture("^[^|]*\\|[^|]*\\|(\\S+)\\s.*? (T.*)", ids, list(var1="", var2="")))`

Comment: Yes, it works as well like that, forgot the mutate. Thanks @LMc for solving them all for me tonight, and thanks all for your help.

Comment: You can do `mutate(strcapture(...))` (no column assignment), it will "add" the new columns. Try `df |> mutate(strcapture("^[^|]*\\|[^|]*\\|(\\S+)\\s.*? (T.*)", ids, list(var1="", var2="")))`

Comment: You are not performing a thorough check of the structure of the string (whether there are exactly two `'T'`'s, for example), but I have no quarrel with that. Often one does not question whether the data format will be correct, the task being merely to extract or replace data, split the string, and so on. If one does not question the data here could you not merely use `.*\\|(\\S+).*(T.*)`? `.*\\|`, in particular, is analogous to your  `.*(T.*)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3sHxo7/1)

Comment: Certainly @CarySwoveland, I'm not doing a perfectly thorough check of the structure, mostly because I know nothing of the origin or consistency of the source. I keyed off of the "second pipe" and "second T" and, based on my experience with imperfect feed formats, didn't want to assume that there would never be more than two pipes, etc. Also, there are other `T`s in the data, and who is to say that it cannot happen at the end of `var2`, for which your shorter query would break. Do I know my halfway checks suffice? No, but experience has taught me to not be naive enough to go that short.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyr::separate_wider_regex()`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_wider_regex(
    ids, 
    patterns = c("^.+\\|.+\\|", var1 = "\\S+", "\\s+T.+", var2 = "T.+") # unnamed elements will be dropped
  )

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   var1           var2                     
#   <chr>          <chr>                    
# 1 HMPI01000001.1 T05X3Ml2_CL10007Cordes1_1
# 2 HMPI31000002.1 T3X3Ml2_CL10157Cordes1_1 
# 3 HMPI01000007.1 T1X3Ml2_CL11231Cordes1_1
```